# The application did not respond but i have no error in debug console

Tags: javascript, discord.js

so i was doing a ping - pong command with slash commands. But when i tried it, i got respond message 'The application did not respond' but i dont get any error which is kinda frustrating.

So this is my main.js file :

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const {Collection} = require('discord.js')
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });
const {loadEvents} = require('./Handlers/eventHandler');
const {loadCommands} = require('./Handlers/comandHandler');
client.command = new Collection();
client.login('').then(()=>{
    loadEvents(client);
    loadCommands(client);
});
```

This is my eventHandler file :

```
function loadEvents(client) {
    const ascii = require('ascii-table');
    const fs = require('fs');
    const table = new ascii().setHeading('Events', 'Status');
    const folders = fs.readdirSync('./Events');
    for(const folder of folders){
        const files = fs.readdirSync(`./Events/${folder}`).filter((file)=>file.endsWith(".js"));
        
        for(const file of files){
            const event = require(`../Events/${folder}/${file}`);

            if(event.rest){
                if(event.once)
                    client.rest.once(event.name, (...args) =>
                    event.execute(...args, client)
                );
                else
                    client.rest.on(event.name, (...args) =>
                        event.execute(...args, client)
                );
            } else{
                if(event.once)
                    client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args, client));
                else client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args, client));
            }
            table.addRow(file, "loaded");
            continue;
        }      
    }
    return console.log(table.toString(), "\nLoaded events");
}
module.exports = {loadEvents};
```

And this is my ping.js file :

```
const {SlashCommandBuilder, CommandInteraction, PersmissionFlagsBits} = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('ping')
    .setDescription('Pong')
    .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PersmissionFlagsBits), //que les admins
    execute(interaction){
        interaction.reply({content: 'Pong !', ephermal: true}) //ephermal = que toi tu le vois
    },
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Try to copy the handler from https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/ see if that one works.

Comment: Hey Blayk, could we see your interaction command handler? I don't think you sent it here.